# NPM broken mime-db missing

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, installation

I had to reinstall Nodejs on my Macbook when I ran into an issue with `npm`.
No matter what I did I always got this output:

```
$ npm 
Error: Cannot find module 'mime-db'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/mime-types/index.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'mime-db'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I did not understand who this was happening. So I installed it one more time in hope that it would be fixed. No luck.

I did fix it after a wasting to much time. That is why I put it on here so that if anybody may walk into the same problem they solve it sooner then I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in the [repo of mime-db](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db) and saw that I was missing [this file](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/master/index.js) in the module that was installed with the pkg. I added this file and now it works.

Good luck!

Comment: indeed I was missing the index.js as you pointed out, however it wasn't until I ran the command with _npm_ instead _yarn_ that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I used following command on node command prompt

> > npm install mime-db

It gave me warning: **unmet dependency** that it requires version 1.12 of mime-db, but it will download version 1.21 of mime-db
i ran the same command again i.e.

> > npm install mime-db

It solved my issue

Good Luck.
Another solution:

I was trying out something else, then I upgraded node package, downloading from node website and installing it, then i did not face this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I deleted mime-db from the node_modules folder. Then I ran

```
npm i mime-db
```

That solved my problem.